# Commit Related to changes is there but the changes are not reflected in the repo , why does this happen?

Tags: git, github, git-commit, github-for-mac

I made some changes in the git repo and commit my changes and pushed those changes in the repo at that time . But after some days I checked the commit history of a file , in that history latest commit is my commits  . 
I used the below command to check the commit history of a specific file

**git log --follow**

Above command shows all the commits related to that file , recent commits is none other than my commit .

when I tried following command .

**git show commit_id**

It shows the changes that i want to keep , but when i look into the file it does not reflect changes related to that commit .

Note : we did not revert that commit .

Comment: Different branch maybe?

Comment: It is the same branch that i pushed , and now trying to find out the changes in file but unable . and commit is there . but when I try to look into the file it does not reflect changes related to that commit , but when i do git show commit_id , it shows the changes .

Comment: What is the last (topmost) change printed by `git log -- path/to/file`? Do you have any (evil) merges?